# how to update eclipse 3.5.2 to eclipse 3.6.2 for latest android?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt, eclipse-3.5

I'm developing an android app with the eclipse as an IDE. My eclipse version is 3.5.2. Now I want to convert the android app to latest version which is for android 4.1. In my eclipse it displays up to only 4.0. So I need update.

When I click the help->check for new software in eclipse. Then it displays some android new components. If I click to install means, then it shows an message requires "eclipse 3.6.2"

I cannot find a way to update the eclipse to 3.6.2. Because if I newly install another eclipse means I want to totally change my sdk path,more changes,etc

So I need to `update eclipse 3.6.2 without deleting, modifying the content` of already had android apps.

So please all give your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not able to upgrade my eclipse.So i new downloaded the eclipse pulsar and installed it with MTJ (mobile tools for java in eclipse).

Now its working fine.

 i just change my program location.

Thanks for all 4 giving ur ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update android sdk from android manager not eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Get the Eclipse version Indigo (3.7)

To upgrade from Galileo(3.5) or Helios(3.6) to Indigo (3.7), you **first** need to add the Indigo software repository as follows:

**1.** Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites

**2.** Click 'Add'

**3.** Enter http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

**4.** Click 'Ok'

Now to upgrade installed software, do the following:

**1.** Help > Check for Updates

**2.** If updates are found, proceed through the install wizard and click
    Finish at the end

**3.** f you are upgrading the platform itself, when you are prompted to
    restart it is strongly recommended to do so. A restart may not be
    required when updating other features, but always select to restart
    if you are unsure

.

Comment: @gian1200 thanks I come to see it now it's released 3 days ago :D